# AngularJS Datatables getting data with SignalR

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, datatables

I have been using the Jquery Datatables plugin with Jquery for quite some time and I am now trying to go over to using AngularJS with SignalR instead to get realtime updating between browsers. I am looking at [Angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) for trying to implement Angular into datables (which I have read isn't that easy) But I cant get it to work.

Simplified the table looks like this. Probably not the prettiest way of solving everything since I am very new to AngularJS.

```
<div ng-controller="ActionEditController">
    <table id="actionsTable" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Field A</th>
                <th>Field B</th>
                <th>Field C</th>
                <th>Field D</th>
                <th>Field E</th>
                <th>Field F</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-show="isNew()">
                <td>
                    <select data-ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in options" data-ng-model="add_action.Status" class="form-control"></select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="add_action.Description" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="add_action.Responsible" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" datetimepicker ng-model="add_action.Deadline" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" datetimepicker ng-model="add_action.Executed" /></td>
                <td width="60">
                    <button name="updateButton" ng-click="add()" ng-show="isNew()" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                    <button name="deleteButton" ng-click="delete(action)" ng-show="!isNew()" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                    <button name="cancelButton" ng-click="abort()" ng-show="isNew()" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="action in actions">
                <td ng-show="!isEdit(action)">{{action.Status}}</td>
                <td ng-show="isEdit(action)">
                    <select data-ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in options" data-ng-model="edit_action.Status" class="form-control"></select>
                </td>
                <td ng-show="!isEdit(action)">{{action.Description}}</td>
                <td ng-show="isEdit(action)"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="edit_action.Description" /></td>
                <td ng-show="!isEdit(action)">{{action.Responsible}}</td>
                <td ng-show="isEdit(action)"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="edit_action.Responsible" /></td>
                <td ng-show="!isEdit(action)">{{action.Deadline | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'}}</td>
                <td ng-show="isEdit(action)"><input type="text" class="form-control" datetimepicker ng-model="edit_action.Deadline" /></td>
                <td ng-show="!isEdit(action)">{{action.Executed | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'}}</td>
                <td ng-show="isEdit(action)"><input type="text" class="form-control" datetimepicker ng-model="edit_action.Executed" /></td>
                <td width="60">
                    <button name="editButton" ng-click="edit(action)" ng-show="!action.IsLocked" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                    <button name="updateButton" ng-click="update()" ng-show="isEdit(action)" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                    <button name="deleteButton" ng-click="delete(action)" ng-show="!action.IsLocked" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                    <button name="cancelButton" ng-click="cancel()" ng-show="isEdit(action)" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So what basically happens with SignalR is that it runs this method when the page is opened.

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
        {
            var query = from f in _db.Actions
                        orderby f.FieldB
                        select new { 
                            FieldA= f.FieldA, 
                            FieldB= f.FieldB,
                            FieldC= f.FieldC,
                            FieldD= f.FieldD,
                            FieldE= f.FieldE,
                            FieldF= f.FieldF
                        };

            await Clients.Caller.all(query);
            await Clients.Caller.allLocks(_locks.Values);
        }
```

The controller is being hooked up like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['datatables', 'ngResource']);
app.controller("ActionEditController", ["$scope", "DTOptionsBuilder", "DTColumnDefBuilder", ActionEditController]);
```

And on the client that called this method it runs theese 2 methods. Which is just checking for locks and applying it to the scope.

```
hubProxy.client.all = function (actions) {
    $scope.actions = actions;
}
hubProxy.client.allLocks = function (locks) {
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.actions.length; i++) {
            $scope.actions[i].IsLocked = false;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < locks.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < $scope.actions.length; j++) {
                if (locks[i] === $scope.actions[j].Id) {
                    $scope.actions[j].IsLocked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
```

And here comes the question. How do I tie this up to the datatables plugin or the angular-datatables plugin?  I Have tried a lot trying to use the examples but can't get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: read this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/05/21/datatable-using-signalr-angularjs-entityframework.aspx

Comment: I have seen this and I am using a lot of the techniques from it. Everything regarding AngularJS, SignalR and the HTML rendering of my table is working. It's the (original) Jquery DataTable functions that are not working. F.eks paging, searching, ordering, row counting and those numbers updating when adding or deleting row. The datatable they mention there is not the same as the plugin DataTable. https://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, though the server object and client object don't look to be the same (different properties).

A few things - assuming it's "actions" you want to bind to your table:

- call ToList() before returning it from the server - since you may not be getting the actual enumerated list, but an IQueryable object
- run $scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.actions = actions;}); since you didn't apply there and it may not be updating the view (can't tell where you're running it from).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried added the toList() on the method, but that didnt really change anything, the data is still beeing returned and displayed the same way. The $scop.actions is beeing applied in the hubProxy.client.all method. If I use ordinary JQuery datatables, the table loads correctly and I can get my custom buttons on the header line. It always says only 2 records found and if I search for anything (even if its in the table) it says no records found.

Comment: The question is how I integrade this with the Datatables plugin? I have looked alot at this site: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWayWithOptions but I think I have to customize that alot to get it to work with how SignalR is adding the data to the $scope